# PHP parse date with Timezone+Offset using strtotime()

Tags: php, datetime, utc, strtotime, timezone-offset

PHP's `strtotime("2015-05-11 00:03:24 UTC+1")` gives me the unix timestamp `1431302604`. But the timestamp should be **1431299004**.

Am I wrong? Or how can I correctly parse this date with PHP 5.4.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php strtotime give a Unix timestamp with default timezone if not specified in input. PHP versions >5 dont change that fact

Comment: Isn't the TZ specified in the input? I think UTC+1 is the timezone. But strtotime() doesn't honor this. That's my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `strtotime("2015-05-11 00:03:24+01:00")`

Comment: Thanks. This gives the correct result. Great! (But I am getting the date strings from an external API. I would need to do some ugly string replacement. I tried to use DateTime::createFromFormat() with no success so far.)

Comment: Well you can remove the `UTC` and just have `strtotime("2015-05-11 00:03:24 +1")`

Comment: Very nice! Thank you!